How to print loop invariant at each loop step?
I am using Frama-C to verify the following program and trying to obtain program states during the verification. For example, I try to print P0 in the following code.
requires x <= y;
ensures x = y;
void test(int x, int y) {
  /*@ loop invariant x <= y;
 */
  while(x <= y) {
    x = x + 1; // P1
  }
}


Could you please show me how to obtain the program state P1?
Many thanks,
Loc

I think that your question needs to be clarified. What plug-in do you use? And what would you expect it to print in this particular case?

-wp and expected P1 is equivalent to x <= y. thanks

If the answer corresponds to your need, I'd suggest that you rename your post "how to see the proof obligation associated to the loop invariant?".

It is not really possible to print the state at a program location with WP. However, one can inspect the provability of some assertions at some program point, and in particular inspect the generated proof obligation.
For example here, we can add an assertion after the instruction to see whether we can prove it or not:
//@ requires x <= y ;
void test(int x, int y) {
  /*@ loop invariant x <= y;
 */
  while(x <= y) {
    x = x + 1;
    //@ assert P1: x <= y ;
  }
}

$ frama-c file.c -wp -wp-print -wp-prop P1
------------------------------------------------------------
  Function test
------------------------------------------------------------

Goal Assertion 'P1' (file a.c, line 8):
Assume {
  Type: is_sint32(x) /\ is_sint32(x_1) /\ is_sint32(y) /\ is_sint32(y_1) /\
      is_sint32(1 + x).
  (* Pre-condition *)
  Have: x_1 <= y_1.
  (* Invariant *)
  Have: x <= y.
}
Prove: x < y.
Prover Alt-Ergo 2.5.3 returns Timeout (Qed:3ms) (2s)

WP performs a few simplification so we do not exactly get that we have to prove x (after the instruction) <= y but x (before the instruction) < y which is equivalent. The proof obligation can also be seen in the GUI in the WP view by double clicking on the corresponding goal.

Note that here, this is basically the property that we have to prove for the preservation of the invariant, and the reason why we can't prove it is that the invariant is incorrect with respect to the condition of the loop: the condition is x <= y, thus the loop stops when x+1 = y, violating the invariant x <= y. according to the expected postcondition, the fix is to make sure that the condition is x < y.
